# Xcode 6.3.2 refactor -> rename not working

Tags: ios, xcode, refactoring

i've recently installed `OS X Yosemite` to upgrade `Xcode 6.3` and have installed `Xcode 6.3.2`.
But it seems like `refactor -> rename` is not working in `Xcode 6.3.2`. (screenshot attached below)
The same thing is happening when i try to rename a file, function or variable from `Edit -> Refactor -> Rename`.
I want to know if anybody else has faced this issue?
If yes, has anybody managed to find a workaround for this?

[image: Error when trying to rename something from <code>Edit -> Refactor</code>]

Comment: Yes this might be Xcode bug..! but you can try this answers from similar post..Hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903426/xcode-4-4-unable-to-rename-classes-variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try selecting the second icon (the one with the bullets) before saving:

[image]

You'll see the list of changes to be made. After clicking SAVE everything will be renamed, even the filenames.

Comment: Thanks @Leandro. Although its very late to answer this question but this might be helpful for others. Answer Accepted :)

Comment: Thanks, @S1LENT WARRIOR! I came across your question recently and yesterday I found the way to do the refactor. So I search your question again and answer it in order to help others. Yes, it was too late for your project, haha. Thanks for accepting it!