# Strange Issue with refactor with rename my file in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am not able to rename my file in my latest `XCode` with the help of Refactor.

**Option I am trying through :** `Menu -> Edit -> Refactor -> Rename`

Its give me error like this :

[image]

I have already Try solution provide in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30504877/xcode-6-3-2-refactor-rename-not-working) answer but didn't get any success.

Still same issue.

Please let me know if nay workaround for this issue.

Comment: How can that possible ? is there any official link or update for this ?

Comment: There is no officially link but there is several issue already registered. Now I unable to find. I read somewhere in blog. But currently I got this (link)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32729804/the-selection-is-not-a-type-that-can-be-renamed-xcode-7]. Hope this helps. Sorry If I miss guide you.

Comment: getting same and I sl9bed with goto .h file and its worki  fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am facing same issue and I search on SO and implemented all suggestions but no luck

from one blog i got solution that in `@Implementation` file reflactor is not working for that you have to use `@Interface` file for rename your file.

Hope this will helps to get out from this issue, Thanks.

**Note** :  By using reflactor it will rename file and all related import every where but at some points its not working like in XIB or in @Implementation file.